# How to modify files in yum.repos.d to install MySQL and others?

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I am trying to install MySQL onto a Fedora 14 VM.
I get the following message when trying to install MySQL:

```
Error Downloading Packages:
zlib-devel-1.2.5-2.fc14.x86_64: failure: Packages/zlib-devel-1.2.5-2.fc14.x86_64.rpm from class-DVD: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
libxml2-devel-2.7.7-2.fc14.x86_64: failure: Packages/libxml2-devel-2.7.7-2.fc14.x86_64.rpm from class-DVD: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I tried adding a repository and got this:

```
[root@dyan src]# yum install mysql mysql-server
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
file:///media/Fedora%2014%20x86_64%20DVD/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///media/Fedora%2014%20x86_64%20DVD/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/core///os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 6 - ""
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: download.fedora.redhat.com_pub_fedora_linux_core_os_. Please verify its path and try again
```

Can someone please tell me how to modify yum.conf (or which appropriate repository to add to yum.repos.d) so that I can install this with yum?

Comment: *How* did you try adding a repository?

Comment: I did `yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/core/$releasever/$basearch/os/` and enabled it.

Comment: Fedora 14 has been EOL for 4 years.

Comment: It's what we're using for class and I have had no problems installing before. Is there no way I can fix this?

Comment: @dabad Doesn't help right now, but Fedora (which I work on) is starting a push for more university involvement, and we'd love to help your instructor update the curriculum to a more recent Fedora version.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops.  This is from the error output:

```
http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/core///os/repodata/repomd.xml
                                                       ^^^
```

Notice those empty elements correspond to the ones from here that are presumably **undefined** shell variables:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo \       
http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/core/$releasever/$basearch/os‌​/
                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm pretty sure `$releasever` should be just `14` and `$basearch` either `i686` or `x86_64`, so that should have been:

```
http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/core/14/x86_64/os‌​/
```

Presuming you are on a 64-bit system (otherwise use `i686` there).

## However...

This whole path is probably no longer valid; you could try:

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/‌​Fedora/x86_64/os/
```

But see discussion in comments.  Presumably you'll also want to remove the bogus repos you've previously added.

Comment: It's gonna need to point at http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/ to work...

Comment: @mattdm So it looks more like: `http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/x86_64/`?  There is a slightly different pattern at the end I notice.

Comment: Something like that? `http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Fedora/$basearch/os/`, I think should work (yum fills in those variables). Not that I _really_ condone this — there are so many unfixed security issues that I think it's somewhat irresponsible. But, hey, if it's the class, do what works....

Comment: @mattdm Apparently `yum` did not fill in those variables, which is why there is this whole problem...

Comment: I *think* what's happening is that _mirrormanager_ isn't returning valid data for F14 anymore, and that's why the end up empty. Skip the `mirrorlist` (or newer `metalink`) and configure the `baseurl`.